# How to compress json in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, compression, payload

Currently we deal with some large data objects in our code.
I am trying to find out a way to check if I can compress this by any way and reduce the size of the payloads.
For example if the input json size is 2 MB, can we compress it to 1MB or so?

I came across various libraries available online.
But not sure which one is trustworthy since I'd like to implement that solution in an enterprise application.
Is anyone aware or implemented any such use case in their code?
Please guide me regarding the same

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be configuring compression on the transport level

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Compression
http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/compression.html
https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#httpcompression
(basically look for "compression" in docs of your project's base http lib)

This will *easily* cut half of JSON *actual transported data* size without any further configuration

---

If it's JSON, you may consider using Protobuf instead, which is something like machine-code representation of JSON (i.e. numbers are float32 instead of string[12] and so on).
But this would have a considerable developer cost.